# What happens to the positive charges in the cloud after a lightning discharge?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, lightning

The clouds before a lightning strike contains ice crystal at upper part of the cloud that is positively charged and lower part of the cloud becomes negatively charged. When enough electrons accumulation occurs then a lightning discharge occurs. Then what will happen to the positive charges of the cloud after the discharge and what are the effects of the -ve charge accumulation on the ground on us as well on the clouds?